# iOS - how to create hideable top UIView from code

Tags: swift, uiview, autolayout

I want to add custom UIView to the main screen of my app, that shows / hide if internet connection is lost / restored. How can I do this from code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide a view in Swift 3 you use:

```
viewVar.isHidden = true
```

If you want to pair that with a reachability check, I use the Reachability Swift library found [here](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift).

I create a function to check reachability like this:

```
 func CheckWiFi() -> Bool


    {


        do {
            try reachability.startNotifier()

        } catch {

            print("Unable to start notifier")
        }


        if reachability.isReachable == true{

            if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi == true{

                reachability.stopNotifier()

                wifi = true

                return wifi

            } else if reachability.isReachableViaWWAN == true{


                reachability.stopNotifier()

                print("Reachable via WWAN simulator")

                return wifi

            }else

            {

                reachability.stopNotifier()

                print("Reachable via Cellular")

                return wifi
            }

        }
        else

        {

            wifi = false

            reachability.stopNotifier()

            print("Not reachable")

            return wifi

        }



    }
```

Then in order to use it, I use the following:

```
 if CheckWiFi() == true
        {

        // show view here

        }

        else

        {
            // hide view here
        }
```

Comment: Thats a totally different question and not part of your original question. I answered your original question. If you have an unrelated question please create another question.

Comment: @MartinMickey If my answer worked for you, please accept it so that others can see it and it can help them. If you have another question regarding resizing views. Please create another question and then add your relevant code so that others can help you with that question.